# elasticsearch cluster stats api return different values on different node

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFrUo.png)

on master _cluster/stats:

```
 "fs" : {
  "total_in_bytes" : 15874832596992,
  "free_in_bytes" : 12578652061696,
  "available_in_bytes" : 12578652061696,
  "spins" : "true"
},
```

node analyzer1(hot) _cluster/stats:

```
   "fs" : {
  "total_in_bytes" : 16274067427328,
  "free_in_bytes" : 12992671711232,
  "available_in_bytes" : 12992671711232,
  "spins" : "true"
},
```

on analyzer2(hot) _cluster/stats:

```
"fs" : {
  "total_in_bytes" : 16274067427328,
  "free_in_bytes" : 12989881016320,
  "available_in_bytes" : 12989881016320,
  "spins" : "true"
},
```

on analyzer3(warm) _cluster:

```
 "fs" : {
  "total_in_bytes" : 14753986846720,
  "free_in_bytes" : 11355335659520,
  "available_in_bytes" : 11355335659520,
  "spins" : "true"
},
```

on analyzer4(warm) _cluster/stats

```
 "fs" : {
  "total_in_bytes" : 17874236866560,
  "free_in_bytes" : 14598999666688,
  "available_in_bytes" : 14598999666688,
  "spins" : "true"
},
```

The five node are in same cluster,and the cluster status is green

Why am I getting different values of fs_total?

note:
    elastic version: 5.2.2
    jdkversion:   openjdk8

Comment: Are these nodes receiving data?

Comment: @Frank analyzer(1,4) are data node and they receiving data all the time .

Comment: @Frank  those data node are receving the data all the time , and the changed value should be free_in_bytes ,but not total_in_bytes

Comment: Each node gets this information from the master (maybe with some caching in the middle) but that will get updated continuously from each of the nodes so getting exactly the same values, even if the requests to the nodes are sent simultaneously, seems unlikely since Elasticsearch is built around eventual consistency.

Comment: @Frank the fact is in past 2 days ,the values does't changed, until now

Comment: Hmm, interesting! Curious for the answer now as well 

Comment: @Frank  master{last week: 15874832596992, now: 15874832596992}  analyzer01{last week:16274067427328,   now:16354156285952,}   analyzer02{last week:16274067427328, now:13875428327424 }   analyzer03{last week:14753986846720 now:17874236866560}  analyzer04{last week: now:17874236866560}    some become lager and some become samller!    why ?  confusioning

Comment: @Frank  in my cluaster each node has 2 es instance
and each instance has 2 attribute : box_type and attr.zone

may be by affected this?

Comment: I've been thinking a bit and I think what's going on [segment merging](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/merge-process.html) (that's a link to the old version but the principles still apply): each shard of an index is a _Lucene index_ on its own. It is autonomously deciding when to merge segments, when it purges deletes, etc. Especially when you delete a lot of records, this can have a major effect when merges happen on one shard but not on the other.

Comment: @Frank free_in_bytes & available_in_bytes may be affected by segment merging。But the changed is total_in_bytes ........may be a bug?  or the total_in_bytes come from free_in_bytes plus used_in_bytes ?

Comment: I think that latter suggestion of you is indeed the case, it's the total capacity of that fs